# Running c++ on Intel Galileo

Tags: c++, opencv, embedded-linux, intel-galileo

I am a student as Technical Computing.

I have a problem, i want to make a car recognition program on a microchip.
I want to use Intel Galileo and OpenCV of the linux image on SD-card.

The linux image is working and i use Tera Term for communication Serial(see link).
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnH0q.png

I have read a lot of forums but i don't know how to run a c++ file on Intel Galileo.
I use Microsoft Visual c++ 2010 Express and windows 7.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: You'll have to cross compile your program from a host system (best linux as well). It's unlikely you can compile directly on your embedded system. Forget about MS Visual Studio, it cannot produce output for your target. You should check out for an appropriate GCC toolchain.

Comment: Thank you, i have one question more. Can i use a virtual box with linux for compiling my programm? thanks

Comment: Yes of course you can use an appropriate VMWare image. You might also be interested in this [blog article](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2013/09/building-gcc-471-arm-cross-toolchain-on.html), where I describe step by step how to build your gcc crosstoolchain (for ARM in that case). It should be easy to change it for your target MCU, if it is supported (which is likely IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with recently announced [Intel® Galileo Development Kit](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iotdevkit). There is a ready-to-go Linux Live Image (debian based) with all the tools (Yocto ADT) you will need for cross-compiling - Eclipse IDE , cross compile toolchain, integration with galileo.

Please refer to [step-by-step tutorial and hello-world example](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/2a/e9/Intel-DeveKit-Tutorial-Guide.pdf) for getting started. You can boot the live image using any virtualization software (eg: vmware player, virtual box) or use natively via USB boot.